# Sample algorithm to "linearize" a graph

Tags: algorithm

Simplifying a business example, I have the following situation:

Some objects should be distributed in a graph in most "linear" way possible for a given "thermometer".

Say, a voyager visits some cities. Several cities are visited multiple times.

So, we have list of cities in ordinate axis (that may be duplicated), and Time in abscissas one.

Now, for a given path, say **(A => X => A => B => C)** we should  display a line, in the "most linear way possible".

[image]

By eg. in the image above, the *green* line is optimal one
**(1 > 2 > 3 > 4 > 5)**

but there could be multiple possible outputs

(1 > 2 > 1 > 4 > 5)
(1 > 2 > 3 > 4 > 5)
(1 > 2 > 6 > 4 > 5)

(3 > 2 > 1 > 4 > 5)
(3 > 2 > 3 > 4 > 5)
(3 > 2 > 6 > 4 > 5)

(6 > 2 > 1 > 4 > 5)
(6 > 2 > 3 > 4 > 5)
(6 > 2 > 6 > 4 > 5)

Is there some algorithms helping in such situations?

Comment: Why isn't 1>2>3>4>5 a good solution?  This seems even completely linear to me.  Do you have control over the sequence of the lines?  If you have, you simply choose the same sequence as the path and you always end up with a linear graph.

Comment: @Patrick: you have reason, 12345 is the ideal solution. The example is just for demonstration purposes.. starting from 3 :)

Comment: I think this problem still suffers from being a little too abstract.  We need a quantitative function for determining "linearity" in your context.  For example, sure it's obvious that the green line is more linear in your new example.  But how would you determine which is more linear of the orange and blue paths?

Answer (score 1):

Construct a graph where a node is a pairing of city+value and time (e.g. A(3)/1).  An edge exists between two nodes that are adjacent in the path (e.g. A(3)/1 to X(2)/2).

The weight of an edge will be the difference in vector (the opposite angle) between the last pair of nodes and the next pair of nodes (this will make the edge weight dynamic depending on where it came from).  Then use Dijkstra to find the minimum distance to the (a) goal.

Example graph (edges given in degrees and are just estimates):

```
                                            Total cost
      0        0      105       15
A31  ->  X22  ->  A13  ->  B44  ->  C55     120

              90       0        0
              ->  A33  ->  B44  ->  C55     90

              115      110      105
              ->  A63  ->  B44  ->  C55     330
```

Comment: thanks. I have no angles defined... I have just an array of cities on Y and array of cities on X. We can make abstraction of time, setting it to 1 for each step. So now, should I "estimate" an angle?... a little embarrassing but if this is the only way...

Comment: @serhio: I think you should start by defining "linear".  I was purposefully abstract because I don't have a clear directive for determining if A is "more linear" than B. I chose to define that as "the route that required the least amount of turning".  Define a function whose minimum value expresses what you think is "most" linear.  An optimization problem needs a value to optimize instead of some softly described trait.